# What does var.set('test') does in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, set

I have a question:

I met in the Tkinter Tkdocs tutorial the form of var.set('test') or meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0). I have been looking around the net but could not find what is **.set()** doing. If I tried to use it in a different way(to see what it does) I get an error "xxx does not have a set attribute". Could you please tell me what exactly is that .set() after the var doing, is that the set method from lists or is a different thing? All searches lead me to the list method but not to something else. I have the feeling that the .set() is doing something else.

Comment: if it is `tk.StingVar()`, `tk.IntVar()`, `tk.DoubleVar()`, etc. then `.set()` assigns value to this object and `.get()` gets value from this object. You can't use directly `=` to get or set value for this object.

Comment: [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: So, it is a Tkinter method but not a Python one.

Thank you for your answer, it really helped me clarify the things!